# read bash environment variable

Tags: linux, bash

i have a program which gives out an environement variable

```
TIME=1328189073
CLIENT[if-modified-since]=Thu, 02 Feb 2012 12:09:40 GMT
HTTP_FILE=/news/rss.xml?edition=uk
HTTP_PORT=80
HTTP_HOST=feeds.bbci.co.uk
HTTP_PROTO=http
CLIENT[host]=feeds.bbci.co.uk
CLIENTID=10
CLIENT[user-agent]=Safari
PWD=/
VERSION=SR.4.2.2.MR.20110523
CLIENT[accept]=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
SHLVL=1
CLIENT[accept-language]=en-gb,en;q=0.5
INTERFACE=192.168.221.196
CLIENT[cache-control]=max-age=0
CLIENT[accept-encoding]=gzip, deflate
HTTP_METHOD=GET
CLIENT[user-agent]
```

however when i try to access one of this variable from a bash script it gives no result

```
echo ${CLIENT[user-agent]} >> ${LOG}
```

however this works

```
echo ${TIME} ${CLIENTID} ${USERNAME} ${IP} ${HTTP_METHOD} ${HTTP_PROTO} ${HTTP_HOST} ${HTTP_PORT} ${HTTP_FILE} ${SIZE} >> ${LOG}
```

any idea why the user-agent fails to show?

Comment: @FatalError - Actually there are two lines with this string. The first one assigns a value, but the second one lacks the assignment operator, so it should do nothing.

Comment: The brackets `[]` seem to cause the problem. Do you really need them in the name? I don't think Bash supports arrays with a non-numeric index.

Comment: yeah the environment variables are given out by the proxy, so it has the brackets..i can read all other non-bracket fields fine..

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "given out by the proxy"? Does the proxy run bash for you? Does it assign to the environment? Or does it return a buch of text?

Answer (score 3):

You need to source your script instead of running it.

```
. set-vars-script.sh
```

Comment: `source set-vars-script.sh` does the job too. But it requires less keyboard typing using a dot :-)

Comment: this didnt work, the scenario is that the proxy dumps all these environment variables and i am trying to read them..

Answer (score 3):

You can not use braces in form **${VAR[ARITHM_EXPR]}**. But you can always extract value of these variables to variables with **VALID** names:

```
  $ set | sed -n '/CLIENT\[user-agent]=/{s|.*=||;p;q;}'
```

Why you don't use Perl/Python for scripting? This resolve your problem:

```
  import os
  print(os.environ['CLIENT[user-agent]'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should declare the array CLIENT before assigning to its elements:

```
declare -A CLIENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit the script assigning all the values to the variables marked for export to subshells?  Can you create a temporary file.  Bash can't export arrays, associative or indexed; but you can use the BASH_ENV variable to name a set-up file for non-interactive subshells.
Be sure to use declare -A CLIENT before assigning values.  Then add something like this *after* all assignments to the CLIENT array

```
    declare -A -p CLIENT > /tmp/bash_env_tmp
    export BASH_ENV=/tmp/bash_env_tmp
```

A new non-interactive subshell will read and execute the file before processing its commands.
If the shell is invoked with the -c option, then you can use a command substitution with on the line calling the subshell to supply the output of the same declare operation as the first commands in the new shell.